# Cannot access lighthttpd from computer

Tags: android, webserver, lighttpd

I created a app that uses light httpd as web server in android it is working as it should i can access it from mobile by typing `localhost:8080` and when i type the ip:port on my computer i cannot access it. But when i connect my phone's net with my computer using  `tethering.`I can access it.Please help me..

This is my config file:

```
## !!!WARNING!!!
## Be careful changing this configuration file!
## Some changes may result in incorrect function of the program.
## Always make backups of configuration files before any changes.
## --------------------------------------------------------------


var.app_dir   = "%app_dir%"
var.http_dir   = "%http_dir%"
var.server_port = "%port%"

server.document-root = http_dir + "/www"
dir-listing.activate = "enable"

server.tag = "DroidPHP v 1.0.2 For Android"


alias.url = ("/phpmyadmin" => http_dir + "/phpmyadmin")
server.errorlog = http_dir + "/logs/lighttpd_sys.log"

server.port = server_port

index-file.names = ("index.xhtml", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm", "index.php")

fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
  ((
    "host" => "127.0.0.1",
    "port" => 9001,
        "bin-path" => app_dir + "/php-cgi -c " + http_dir + "/conf/php.ini",
        "bin-environment" => (
             "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "16",
             "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000",
             "PHPRC" => http_dir + "/www/php.ini",
         "TMPDIR" => app_dir + "/tmp"
        ),
    "min-procs" => 1,
    "max-procs" => 1,
    "idle-timeout" => 20
  ))
)


##  MimeType handling
## -------------------
##
## Use the "Content-Type" extended attribute to obtain mime type if
## possible
##
mimetype.use-xattr        = "disable"

##
## mimetype mapping
##
mimetype.assign             = (
  ".appcache"     =>      "text/cache-manifest",    
  ".pdf"          =>      "application/pdf",
  ".sig"          =>      "application/pgp-signature",
  ".spl"          =>      "application/futuresplash",
  ".class"        =>      "application/octet-stream",
  ".ps"           =>      "application/postscript",
  ".torrent"      =>      "application/x-bittorrent",
  ".dvi"          =>      "application/x-dvi",
  ".gz"           =>      "application/x-gzip",
  ".pac"          =>      "application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig",
  ".swf"          =>      "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  ".tar.gz"       =>      "application/x-tgz",
  ".tgz"          =>      "application/x-tgz",
  ".tar"          =>      "application/x-tar",
  ".zip"          =>      "application/zip",
  ".mp3"          =>      "audio/mpeg",
  ".m3u"          =>      "audio/x-mpegurl",
  ".wma"          =>      "audio/x-ms-wma",
  ".wax"          =>      "audio/x-ms-wax",
  ".ogg"          =>      "application/ogg",
  ".wav"          =>      "audio/x-wav",
  ".gif"          =>      "image/gif",
  ".jpg"          =>      "image/jpeg",
  ".jpeg"         =>      "image/jpeg",
  ".png"          =>      "image/png",
  ".xbm"          =>      "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xpm"          =>      "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xwd"          =>      "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".css"          =>      "text/css",
  ".html"         =>      "text/html",
  ".htm"          =>      "text/html",
  ".js"           =>      "text/javascript",
  ".asc"          =>      "text/plain",
  ".c"            =>      "text/plain",
  ".cpp"          =>      "text/plain",
  ".log"          =>      "text/plain",
  ".conf"         =>      "text/plain",
  ".text"         =>      "text/plain",
  ".txt"          =>      "text/plain",
  ".spec"         =>      "text/plain",
  ".dtd"          =>      "text/xml",
  ".xml"          =>      "text/xml",
  ".mpeg"         =>      "video/mpeg",
  ".mpg"          =>      "video/mpeg",
  ".mov"          =>      "video/quicktime",
  ".qt"           =>      "video/quicktime",
  ".avi"          =>      "video/x-msvideo",
  ".asf"          =>      "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".asx"          =>      "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".wmv"          =>      "video/x-ms-wmv",
  ".bz2"          =>      "application/x-bzip",
  ".tbz"          =>      "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".tar.bz2"      =>      "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".odt"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
  ".ods"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
  ".odp"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
  ".odg"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
  ".odc"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
  ".odf"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
  ".odi"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
  ".odm"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
  ".ott"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
  ".ots"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
  ".otp"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
  ".otg"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
  ".otc"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",
  ".otf"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",
  ".oti"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",
  ".oth"          =>      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",

# make the default mime type application/octet-stream.
  ""              =>      "application/octet-stream",
)

#file upload
server.max-request-size = 1000000
server.network-backend = "writev"
server.upload-dirs =( app_dir + "/tmp" )
```

Comment: localhost means the machine your client runs on, not your computer. also, is your phone on the same network your computer is on ?

Comment: see when i type localhot:8080 in my phone browser i can see the server page but if i get the ip of my and type it my coputer with port i cannot access it but if i tether my computer than i can accesse it..

Comment: your web server is running on your phone ?

Comment: also, where did you get `10.120.170.214̀  from, and why not bind to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: the port appears to be 9001 in your code ?

Comment: phpmyadmin ? does that imply you are also running mysql on your phone ?

Comment: now I'm curious. what's the point of having all this on a phone ?

Comment: i want to make my phone a webserver..

Comment: I can see that, but what for?